# (Python) Website loads with selenium but the connection becomes 'Not secure' after proceeding to checkout

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, security, ssl

As the title of my question implies, I connect to a website (https://www.bestbuy.com/) and the connection is originally secure. My script then navigates to an item, adds it to the cart, and proceeds to checkout. At this point, the connection becomes 'Not secure' for some reason - this does not happen when I proceed to checkout manually on a browser. I just started learning selenium a few days ago (the issue at hand arose from a project I'm using to aid in teaching myself), and I have no idea what could be causing this.

I have searched for an answer but cannot seem to find one. I would really appreciate if anyone could suggest a solution or even a cause!
I have attached images of what the connection looks like before and after the payment page has been visited. Not really sure what code segment would be relevant to this specific issue as I proceed to checkout by using .click() on the proper button.

## Insecure

[image: Insecure]

## Secure

[image: Secure]

Comment: I would open up the DevTools and see if there are any warnings. You may find that some file (even if it’s just an image) is being loaded in over http and not https, which would cause an insecure warning in the address bar.